# Read current "metadata change counter" (version count) of a table

Tags: firebird

In Firebird every table has an internal 1 Byte "metadata change counter" which limits altering of each table to 255.

Is there a way to read the current value of this counter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each change you make in table's structure is recorded in **RDB$FORMATS**
>   system table. When you make 255 changes, you must do a backup and
>   subsequent restore - which resets counter for all tables.

[Source](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq239/)

To get number of changes for a table you can use :

```
select max(t.rdb$format) from rdb$formats t
where
 t.rdb$relation_id = (select t2.rdb$relation_id from rdb$relations t2   
    where (t2.rdb$relation_name = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'))
```

Comment: The latest format version is also directly available in `RDB$RELATIONS` in column `RDB$FORMAT` (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest query to get the current (highest) format version of a table is

```sql
select rdb$format
from rdb$relations
where rdb$relation_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
```